# how to decrypt the TLS/SSL package content in wireshark pcapng log file?

Tags: networking, certificate, ssl-certificate, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have PEM key and RSA key on hand, when I was trying to analysis the wireshark pcapng file which logged on my networking nodes, the tls encrypted tls/ssl package contents can NOT be decrypted as shown below:

[image]

The pem key info printed with openssl(x509) as shown below:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        17:.......................:5d
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Seattle, O=changeme changeme Company, OU=IT, CN=changeme Corporate Issuing CA 01
    Validity
        Not Before: Sep  9 09:27:27 2019 GMT
        Not After : Sep  8 09:27:27 2020 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=DC, L=ST, O=changeme changeme Company, OU=IT, CN=cmeptgapp.changeme.net
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00..........................................d4:
                ..............
                eb..........................................af:
                44:6f
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            FA:58:...................3C:88
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:AB:1......................................:21

        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

            Full Name:
              URI:http://crl.changeme.com/pki/tdtd

        Authority Information Access: 
            CA Issuers - URI:http://crl.changeme.com/pki/dtfh.crt
            OCSP - URI:http://whoknows.changeme.com/whoknows
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
        1.3............d...
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication
        1............10: 
           .
        X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
            Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.45807.509.1.2
              CPS: http://nobody.changeme.com/policies/nobodykonows.html

        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:cmeptgapp.changeme.net
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     05................................................:e4:
     ......................................................................
     ...................................................:7b
```

I have tried to decrypt the package content by:

**1.** edit the wireshark/preference/protocol/ssl/RSA key

**2.** editcap command

but unfortunately no one works, possibly I used the commands wrong. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The client and server probably exchanged keys using perfect forward secrecy (such as ECDH, DHE-RSA, ECDHE-RSA or ECDHE-ECDSA). Check the previous two packets in the TLS session.

It is not possible to decrypt the TLS traffic if you only have the private RSA key when Diffie-Hellman key exchange is used. You will instead need to log the per-session secrets by using an SSLKEYLOGFILE, as explained in the [Wireshark wiki TLS page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS).

Another option is to decrypt the TLS traffic using a TLS proxy like [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) or [SSLsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but seems the SSLKEYLOGFILE only works on client side which been generated by clients? does here a way we could also generate the SSLKEYLOGFILE file on server side to decrypt each package passed to the https server?

Comment: @Tony: SSLKEYLOGFILE support on the server side is still rare, but things are changing. OpenSSL 1.1.1 includes support for SSLKEYLOGFILE. Also, see this SE thread on [Extracting openssl pre-master secret from apache2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/215358/extracting-openssl-pre-master-secret-from-apache2/215397#215397).

A more common solution, however, is to instead use an external TLS termination proxy to perform the decryption. You will then be able to capture/inspect cleartext HTTP between the TLS proxy and web server.